# How to remove specific categories from posts?

Tags: categories, wp-query

I need to select all posts from database without fetching some categories.
For example I fetch posts with this code:

```
$featuredPosts = new WP_Query();
$featuredPosts->query('showposts=40');
```

So, now, how can i remove categories with id of: 22, 23 and 24?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make query like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'category__not_in' => array( 2, 6 ) ) );
```

2, 6 being the category ID you want to exclude.